# Alfresco SetInherite permission webscript security api

Tags: javascript, lucene, alfresco

I try to create script for alfresco for set Inherit permission, but i don't know if my script is correct this is my script :

Inherit.post.xml

```
<webscript>
<shortname>Inherit Permission</shortname>
<description>Inherit Permission of a User or  Group from a Folder or Space</description>
<url>/set/folder/permission/inherit/?folderName={folderName}</url>
<format default="html"/>
<transaction>required</transaction>
<authentication>user</authentication>
```

Inherit.post.html

```
<html>
<body>
<p>${myStatus}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

InheritePermission.post.js

```
//search for the folder node using lucene search
var folderNode =  search.luceneSearch("TYPE:\"{http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}folder\" AND @cm\\:name:"+args.folderName);

//make sure we only get one node

if(folderNode.length == 1){

folderNode[0].setInheritsPermissions(false);

model.myStatus = "Héritage permis";
}else  if (folderNode.length == 0){
//no node was found
model.myStatus = "Folder not found";
}else{
//either greater than two  was found
model.myStatus = "Duplicate folder found";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File name of web script should be like below.

- helloworld.get.desc.xml (**your name is wrong it should be Inherit.post.desc.xml**)
- helloworld.get.js
- helloworld.get.html.ftl
- helloworld.get.xml.ftl
- helloworld.get.html.400.ftl
- helloworld.get.xml.400.ftl
- helloworld.get.config.xml
- helloworld.get.properties

Answer (score 0):

Naming convention followed by webscript in alfresco are as follow

```
<webscriptname>.<HTTPMethod>.desc.xml (For description file)
<webscriptname>.<HTTPMethod>.js (For javascript controller file of webscript)
<webscriptname>.<HTTPMethod>.<outputformat>.ftl (For response/template file)
<webscriptname>.<HTTPMethod>.properties (Property file)
```

> **HTTPMethod**: values could be get,post,put,delete based on type of webscript required but it has to be consistent for all files(obviously :) ).

and

> **OutputFormat**: output format represent type of output you are expecting values could be json,xml,html based on your requirement.